# JOIN of two tables does not return rows

Tags: join, abap, opensql

I created three tables `Z588B`, `Z588T`, `ZFINALTABLE` which I want to populate using SQL in function builder.

First I tried to join these tables I got error

> for pooled tables cluster tables and projection views join is not allowed

So I created temp table to store the data from `T588B`, `T588T` tables so I can join them using the temp tables into the ZFINALTABLE which the output fields that I need.

I was able to populate `Z588B`, `Z588T`  with the data that I need but the JOIN using these temp tables did not return any data.

My steps:

1. Created Function Module `Z_BAPI_TESTP_FM` using SE37
2. In the Import tab I defined the Parameters.

   ```
    MANDT   TYPE    ZTESTPA30-MANDT   Client
    USERG   TYPE    ZTESTPA30-USERG   User group
   ```
3. Declared temp tables that I had created using se11

   ```
   Z588B   LIKE    Z588B   Temp Structure for T588B
   Z588T   LIKE    Z588T   Temp Structure for T588T
   Z582S   LIKE    Z582S   Temp Structure for T582S

   ZFINALTABLE LIKE Z588BTEST Temp Structure for ZFINALTABLE
   ```
4. Entered my sql query in the source code.

   ```
   FUNCTION Z_BAPI_TEST_FM.
      *"----------------------------------------------------------------------
      *"*"Local Interface:
      *"  IMPORTING
      *"     VALUE(MANDT) TYPE  ZTESTPA30-MANDT
      *"     VALUE(USERG) TYPE  ZTESTPA30-USERG
      *"  EXPORTING
      *"     VALUE(RETRUN) TYPE  BAPIRET2
      *"  TABLES
      *"      ZPA30 STRUCTURE  ZPA30
      *"      Z588B STRUCTURE  Z588B
      *"      Z588T STRUCTURE  Z588T
      *"      Z582S STRUCTURE  Z582S
      *"      Z588BTEST STRUCTURE  Z588BTEST
      *"----------------------------------------------------------------------

   TABLES: Z588B, Z588T, ZFINALTABLE.

      select MANDT USERG MNTYP MENUE INFTY  INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE Z588B 
      from T588B CLIENT SPECIFIED
      WHERE MANDT = MANDT AND USERG = USERG AND MNTYP = 'I'.

      select MANDT SPRSL MNTYP MENUE DTEXT INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE Z588T
      from T588T CLIENT SPECIFIED
      WHERE MANDT = MANDT AND MNTYP = 'I' AND SPRSL = 'EN'.

      Select a~MANDT AS MANDT  a~USERG AS USERG a~MNTYP AS MNTYP a~MENUE AS MENUE 
      a~INFTY AS INFTY b~SPRSL AS SPRSL b~DTEXT As DTEXT
      INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE ZFINALTABLE
      FROM Z588B  AS a LEFT JOIN Z588T AS b ON a~MNTYP = b~MNTYP.

   ENDFUNCTION.
   ```

Was able to load the data on Z588B, Z588T for the given parameter but the final sql with the join is not returning the data in ZFINALTABLE table.

Can you anyone tell why the last sql using JOIN is not returning any data in the ZFINALTABLE ?

Comment: ZFINALTABLE is not a table parameter in your function module, therefore it wouldn't return the results of table ZFINALTABLE to the caller. Or is the query itself not working as intended?

Comment: I had declared the ZFINALTABLE as table parameter (Ingore the comments in the code, it is old one). The query itself is not working. Select a~MANDT AS MANDT  a~USERG AS USERG a~MNTYP AS MNTYP a~MENUE AS MENUE a~INFTY AS INFTY b~SPRSL AS SPRSL b~DTEXT As DTEXT
    INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE ZFINALTABLE
    FROM Z588B  AS a LEFT JOIN Z588T AS b ON a~MNTYP = b~MNTYP. is not working. The first 2 quires are working fine.

Comment: ah, now I see it. You can't query internal tables with SELECT. Query 1 and 2 query on table T558B and T558T, both existing tables in the DDIC, probably with entries in them. You select some entries in your internal tables Z588B and Z588T, but your 3rd select doesn't query those internal tables but the "real" transparent tables in your DDIC. If those are empty, so is your query result. Solution: iterate (LOOP AT...) over your ITAB Z588B , use READ TABLE to get the corresponding entry in ITAB Z588T and create a new row in ZFINALTABLE with values from both ITABs. Or query T588B and T588T instead.

Comment: You do not understand the difference between defining working area/internal table with header and the transparent table. The first two selects are storing the data from the database into internal tables with headers which only by your design are named exactly like the transparent (database) tables.

Comment: I tried to join the T588B and T588T directly but had an error "for pooled tables cluster tables and projection views join is not allowed"

Comment: I used internal table and loaded the data required in the join and then looped through the internal tables finally delivering the output for the function module.
 
I really wanted to avoid the loop but seems like I had to go through the  pain of looping the tables.

Comment: if you use JOIN it will cause performance issue. Try BINARY SEARCH instead. then APPEND all your data into FINAL TABLE.

Answer (score 0):

I just convert Jagger valuable comment into an answer for future visitors.

You are confusing different types of tabular data in ABAP: internal and transparent tables.

1. [Internal tables](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/abenitab_oview.htm) are stored in memory and are relevant only during program runtime, After that they are flushed and are gone forever.
2. [Transparent tables](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-us/abentransparent_table_glosry.htm), aka DB tables, reside in RDBMS, which can be different between different SAP installations, but SAP uses unified [OpenSQL language](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/abenopen_sql_oview.htm) to access this data so DB-backend is not important.

So SELECTs/JOINs are used only for DB queries written in ABAP Sql language, and LOOPs and other statements are used for querying internal tables.

So main point of confusion is: you named parameters of function module **exactly the same** as DB tables. Your intention was to join and to query two tables `Z588B` and `Z588T` formed in the first two SELECTs but in fact you queried DB tables with the same names **Z588B** and **Z588T** and the JOIN condition was not met.

What you need is to join your two itabs found on first two steps. Joining internal tables is more tricky and may be implemented by [parallel cursor technique](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/Snippets/ABAP+Code+for+Parallel+Cursor+-+Loop+Processing) to keep a good performance contrary to usual LOOP. Consider this sample:

```
" Note: two itabs must be sorted by the same key which they joined by

sort: lt_vbpa by kunnr,  "Sorting by key is very important
      lt_kna1 by kunnr.  "Same key which is used for where condition is used here
loop at lt_vbpa into wa_vbpa.
  read lt_kna1 into wa_kna1     " This sets the sy-tabix
       with key kunnr = wa_vbpa-kunnr
       binary search.
  if sy-subrc = 0.              "Does not enter the inner loop
    v_kna1_index = sy-tabix.
    loop at lt_kna1 into wa_kna1 from v_kna1_index. "Avoiding Where clause
      if wa_kna1-kunnr <> wa_vbpa-kunnr.  "This checks whether to exit out of loop
        exit.
      endif.

****** Filling your final itab  ZFINALTABLE******

   endloop. "KNA1 Loop
  endif.
endloop.  " VBPA Loop
```

And only after that you will be able to update your DB table with the rows of your newly constructed internal table like this:

```
UPDATE ZFINALTABLE FROM TABLE @zfinaltable.
```